# How does roxygen handle ... in function argument

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have function that takes in one argument only. To error check with `nargs()` I include `...`.

Problem is, when I check package with roxygen, I get warning.

Code and error below. Entire [script on GitHub](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R). How to reflect this? I tried checking [Generating Rd files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html), but no avail

```
#' Show Palette Photo
#' @description This function shows photo that inspired a palette
#' @param name palette name
#' @param ... Numeric, complex, or logical vectors.
#' @usage ShowPalettePhoto(name)
#' @return image of reference photo with palette
#' @import jpeg
#' @export
#' @examples
#' ShowPalettePhoto("GoldenTemple")
#' ShowPalettePhoto("Kulfi")
#' ShowPalettePhoto("AmritsariPedeWaliLassi")
ShowPalettePhoto <- function(name=NULL,...){

 if (nargs() > 1){
    stop("Enter 1 valid palette. Run ListPalette() for list of palettes.")
  }

  ###snipped code
}
```

Commands I run

```
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)
document()
check()
```

Warning I receive ...... how to resolve?

```
R CMD check results
0 errors | 1 warning  | 0 notes
checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
Codoc mismatches from documentation object 'ShowPalettePhoto':
ShowPalettePhoto
  Code: function(name = NULL, ...)
  Docs: function(name)
  Argument names in code not in docs:
    ...
  Mismatches in argument default values:
    Name: 'name' Code: NULL Docs:
```

Comment: Did you regenerate your documentation and rebuild your package before checking it?

Comment: Your `#' @usage ShowPalettePhoto(name)` line is wrong.  Don't put in any usage line, let Roxygen generate the usage for you.

Comment: @Dason I ran `document()` before `check()`. What do you mean by rebuild. I thought package gets built with `build()`. Please clarify.

Comment: @user2554330 Ok let me try

Comment: @user2554330 Your solution works, thank you.